# SSH to 2 local machines via Unix server

Tags: ssh, scp, putty

Here is the situation: I have a Windows home machine *Home* which I can connect to *Foo*, a Unix server via ssh. Then I can ssh from my Unix work machine *Bar* to this same server *Foo*.

```
Windows           Unix             Unix
  __               __     ssh       __
 |  | ----------> |  | <---------- |  |
 |__|    ssh      |__| ----------> |__|
 Home             Foo     ssh -R    Bar
```

My first goal is to be able to open a ssh-shell on Bar from Home (I use putty on Windows). My understanding is that I have to open a reverse ssh tunnel from Bar choosing an arbitrary port say 2210.

```
netstat -putan
```

displays:

```
Bar.x.x.ip:2210
127.0.0.1:2210
::1:2210
```

Then I don't know how from Home I can open a terminal to Bar.

My second and last problem is that I want (using scp) to copy files from Foo to Bar while typing on *Home*, like I would naturally do it but typing on *Bar*.

Is it possible to guide into the procedure to make this work?
Thanks

Comment: What client do you have on windows? putty? cygwin?

Comment: I use putty on Windows

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correct you are not able to `ssh` from Foo to Bar, otherwise it would be as easy as:

```
win> ssh -L 2210:bar:22 user@foo
```

Where you probably replace `ssh` with PuTTY and setup the correct tunnel, but this will hopefully illustrate the way you should set it up...

Then you can start a `ssh` session to bar using:

```
win> ssh -p 2210 bar-user@localhost
```

If you can only `ssh` from Bar to Foo you first need to setup a tunnel from Bar to Foo using:

```
bar# ssh -R 2210:localhost:22 user@foo
```

If this connection is up you can start a connection from Windows to Foo using:

```
win> ssh -L 2210:localhost:2210 user@foo
```

This way you have both sides connected to Foo and you should be able to start a connection using:

```
win> ssh -p 2210 bar-user@localhost
```